# Вставка графики OpenGL

Tags: c++builder, графика, opengl

Как вставить OpenGL графику в Borland C++ Builder 1.0?

Comment: [Работа с OpenGL](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/index.html) - там неплохо всё описано.

Comment: [Setting up OpenGL in C++Builder](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10528).